# Add total row to bottom of SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, grouping

I have an SQL Statement that gets daily sales, but I would like to total these rows, possibly with the use of CTE.

My code is as follows, I tried using GROUPING and ROLLUP but to no avail. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '20161101'
 DECLARE @FinishDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '20161102'

 SELECT salesquery.Department, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.Cost ELSE -salesquery.Cost END) AS 'Cost',
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.[GP $] ELSE -salesquery.[GP $] END) AS 'GP $',  
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) AS 'TotalExGST', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) * 1.1 AS 'TotalInclGST', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.[GP $] ELSE -salesquery.[GP $] END) / SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) * 100 AS 'GP %'

    FROM 
      (SELECT 
        iid.DepartmentCode AS 'Department', 
        ci.InvoiceDate,
        ci.Type,
        ci.InvoiceCode,
        SUM(cid.ExtActualCost) AS 'Cost', 
        SUM(cid.ExtPrice) + MAX(ci.Freight) + MAX(ci.Other) AS 'TotalExGST', 
        (SUM(cid.ExtPrice) - SUM(cid.ExtActualCost)) AS 'GP $',
        (CASE WHEN SUM(cid.ExtPrice) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((SUM(cid.ExtPrice) - SUM(cid.ExtActualCost)) / SUM(cid.ExtPrice)) END) * 100 as 'GP %'



      FROM CustomerInvoice ci
      JOIN CustomerInvoiceDetail cid ON ci.InvoiceCode = cid.InvoiceCode
      JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid ON cid.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode

      WHERE ci.IsVoided = 0
        AND ci.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @FinishDate
      GROUP BY ci.invoicecode, iid.DepartmentCode, ci.Type, ci.InvoiceDate) salesquery

  GROUP BY salesquery.Department
```

This gives me sample output like so

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Department ║ Cost         ║ GP $         ║ Total Ex GST ║ Total Incl GST ║ GP %      ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ EP         ║ 4720.262000  ║ 8076.918000  ║ 13179.180000 ║ 14497.098000   ║ 61.285400 ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ F          ║ 11307.420000 ║ 11465.690000 ║ 23210.110000 ║ 25531.121000   ║ 49.399500 ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ M          ║ 85.860000    ║ 45.310000    ║ 131.170000   ║ 144.287000     ║ 34.542900 ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

I would like table to output with table row 'Total', which adds the rows above, and averages the last column.

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦════════════╗
║ Department ║ Cost         ║ GP $         ║ Total Ex GST ║ Total Incl GST ║ GP %       ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╣
║ EP         ║ 4720.262000  ║ 8076.918000  ║ 13179.180000 ║ 14497.098000   ║ 61.285400  ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╣
║ F          ║ 11307.420000 ║ 11465.690000 ║ 23210.110000 ║ 25531.121000   ║ 49.399500  ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╣
║ M          ║ 85.860000    ║ 45.310000    ║ 131.170000   ║ 144.287000     ║ 34.542900  ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬════════════╣
║ Total      ║ 11612.23     ║ 19587.70     ║ etc          ║ etc            ║ AVG(Above) ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: As jdl134679 suggests, this sounds like something an application should handle as a matter of displaying the data. It should be easy to efficiently total the values while formatting rows for display rather than having the database process the query twice.

Comment: Nice tables! How to do this? :)

Comment: @VadimLoboda http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables :)

Answer (score 4):

I tend to use `GROUPING SETS`.  For the last `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((salesquery.Department), ())
```

You can change the `Department` using the lazy method (`COALESCE(salesquery.Department, 'Total') as Department`) or the correct method (using `GROUPING()`).

Answer (score 2):

Use a `UNION` at the end to re-sum your original query and append it... something like this (as a matter of concept):

```
DECLARE @StartDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '20161101'
DECLARE @FinishDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = '20161102'

SELECT a.*
FROM (

    -- Your original query here

) AS a

UNION

SELECT SUM(b.This), SUM(b.That) FROM (

    -- Your original query here

) AS b
```

There's probably a better way to do it, but that would work.  Regardless of how, you need to requery the original set anyway (or use a cursor and go RBAR, but that'd be even worse)

I'd be inclined to say that using whatever UI display to sum the original result (without including it in the query) would probably be a more standard approach.

Comment: Yes, yes I did :)  (actually, I hadn't thought of that, but sure, it might work)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION and revome the group by salesquery.Department in the united select

```
 SELECT salesquery.Department, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.Cost ELSE -salesquery.Cost END) AS 'Cost',
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.[GP $] ELSE -salesquery.[GP $] END) AS 'GP $',  
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) AS 'TotalExGST', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) * 1.1 AS 'TotalInclGST', 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.[GP $] ELSE -salesquery.[GP $] END) / SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) * 100 AS 'GP %'

    FROM 
      (SELECT 
        iid.DepartmentCode AS 'Department', 
        ci.InvoiceDate,
        ci.Type,
        ci.InvoiceCode,
        SUM(cid.ExtActualCost) AS 'Cost', 
        SUM(cid.ExtPrice) + MAX(ci.Freight) + MAX(ci.Other) AS 'TotalExGST', 
        (SUM(cid.ExtPrice) - SUM(cid.ExtActualCost)) AS 'GP $',
        (CASE WHEN SUM(cid.ExtPrice) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((SUM(cid.ExtPrice) - SUM(cid.ExtActualCost)) / SUM(cid.ExtPrice)) END) * 100 as 'GP %'



      FROM CustomerInvoice ci
      JOIN CustomerInvoiceDetail cid ON ci.InvoiceCode = cid.InvoiceCode
      JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid ON cid.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode

      WHERE ci.IsVoided = 0
        AND ci.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @FinishDate
      GROUP BY ci.invoicecode, iid.DepartmentCode, ci.Type, ci.InvoiceDate) salesquery

  GROUP BY salesquery.Department

  UNION 


 SELECT 'Total , 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.Cost ELSE -salesquery.Cost END) ,
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.[GP $] ELSE -salesquery.[GP $] END) ,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) , 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) * 1.1 , 
    SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.[GP $] ELSE -salesquery.[GP $] END) / SUM(CASE WHEN salesquery.Type = 'Invoice' THEN salesquery.TotalExGST ELSE -salesquery.TotalExGST END) * 100 

    FROM 
      (SELECT 
        iid.DepartmentCode AS 'Department', 
        ci.InvoiceDate,
        ci.Type,
        ci.InvoiceCode,
        SUM(cid.ExtActualCost) AS 'Cost', 
        SUM(cid.ExtPrice) + MAX(ci.Freight) + MAX(ci.Other) AS 'TotalExGST', 
        (SUM(cid.ExtPrice) - SUM(cid.ExtActualCost)) AS 'GP $',
        (CASE WHEN SUM(cid.ExtPrice) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE ((SUM(cid.ExtPrice) - SUM(cid.ExtActualCost)) / SUM(cid.ExtPrice)) END) * 100 as 'GP %'



      FROM CustomerInvoice ci
      JOIN CustomerInvoiceDetail cid ON ci.InvoiceCode = cid.InvoiceCode
      JOIN InventoryItemDepartment iid ON cid.ItemCode = iid.ItemCode

      WHERE ci.IsVoided = 0
        AND ci.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @FinishDate
      GROUP BY ci.invoicecode, iid.DepartmentCode, ci.Type, ci.InvoiceDate) salesquery
```